# cisco commands in foreach doesn't function

Tags: php, cisco

I am trying to send some commands to a cisco router, the commands are stored into a db and when i want to execute that command i send it to a function.

```
$command = "configure terminal<br />router bgp 444444<br />address-family ipv4<br />neighbor x.x.x.x prefix-list NAME out<br />end<br />clear ip bgp x.x.x.x soft out";
```

If i declare the commands one by one it function:

```
//execute the command
public function execCommand()
{
    $this->_send('config terminal');
    $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);
    $this->_send('router bgp 444444');
    $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);
    $this->_send('address-family ipv4');
    $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);
    $this->_send('neighbor x.x.x.x prefix-list NAME out');
    $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);
    $this->_send('end');
    $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);
    $this->_send('clear ip bgp x.x.x.x soft out');
    $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);
    return true;

} //execCommand
```

If i pass the command like this doesn't function:

```
//execute the command
public function execCommand($command)
{
    $cmd = explode("<br />",$command);
    foreach($cmd as $row){
        $this->_send($row);
        $this->_readTo($this->_prompt);         
    }
    return true;

} //execCommand
```

I use the PHP for CIsco class http://www.soucy.org/
Thanks

Comment: Is it ok to have both `configure terminal` and `config terminal`? Maybe one command is wrong and that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: would be useful if you shared the contents of your `$command` variable

Comment: @u_mulder how did I miss that? :) thanks!

Comment: the problem is not config or configure both are ok, the problem is that on foreach send succefully until address-family ipv4 and then stop. i was thinking that the problem was that the foreach send the commands too quick and i have try using usleep but nothing change.

Comment: nobody know what problem can be? thanks